# SQL Query to enclose column with quotes when it has |

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, bi-publisher

A table has the following details

```
Course_Number                   Description

10                             Lean Six Sigma - White Belt 2022 | Mar. 12-Abr
12                             Gold Six Sigma || Got it
13                             Diamond Six Sigma || Black Belt
13                             Six Lean Sigma
```

Is there a way i can enclose the data with quotes " in case if the description column has "|".

So the output should be like

```
Course_Number                   Description

10                             "Lean Six Sigma - White Belt 2022 | Mar. 12-Abr"
12                             "Gold Six Sigma || Got it"
13                             "Diamond Six Sigma || Black Belt"
13                             Six Lean Sigma
```

Comment: Sure you can, but why?  Either enclose the column with quotes or don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking at this to make it easier for people to copy/paste and avoid delimiter issues, then I think transforming your data may be considered. If you are still looking for an answer to above, then you could create a case <s>statement</s> expression and use multiple concat() or use ||.

```
select course_number, 
case 
 when description like '%|%' then '"' || description || '"' 
 else description 
end description
from course_data
```

Comment: `case` _expression_, not statement. (Still upvoted.)